# Rails 3.2.11 SSL Configuration

Tags: ssl, https, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

So I'm having some issues with getting my rails app to run on https. And I'm just trying to narrow down the possibilities with what is causing the issue.

I was wondering if I am missing any steps with configuring the Rails application itself (not the web server):

1. In `config/environments/production.rb`

   Uncomment this line:`config.force_ssl = true`

   Source: http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/
2. Additional configuration for the Devise gem

   In `config/environments/production.rb`

   Add the following lines:

   `config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
   config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
   config.to_prepare { Devise::PasswordsController.force_ssl }`

   Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29

Is there any other steps I am missing? Currently I am seeing a 'This webpage is not available' message when trying to hit my server, not seeing any errors in the log files for the web server or Rails app.

I am seeing this error message though from my web browser: `Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Thanks

Comment: As per your this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-SSL-%28HTTPS%29 
link have you configured your server for ssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the configuration in the question for the Rails app itself was setup properly and there were no other steps required there.

**The issue was related to the SSL cert not being setup correctly.**

Comment: Please make this into an answer to the question or delete both the question and the answer.  Ideally make it into an answer so it can help people who run into a similar issue in the future.  Delete it if you cannot provide the answer so people aren't frustrated by its existence if they come looking for an answer.